# XHTML in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

It is possible to display XHTML fully in Crystal Reports?
I have a field which I set to display with HTML tags, but it ignores many of the tags I need, such as

.  It would be nice if the font was set by the XHTML as well.

If not, is there a reporting tool with the features of Crystal Reports but is better at rendering XHTML?

Answer (score 1):

I did not test so much XTHML documents but I know that [Crystal-Clear](http://inetsoftware.de/products/crystalclear/) has the ability to display HTML documents as well as Crystal Reports. As Crystal-Clear is a Java solution they use the JEditorPane with the HTMLEditorKit. It sounds like this would also allow usage of XHTML documents. As Crystal Clear can also open Crystal Reports reports you could try your report with this solution. You need to specify the "text interpretation" property for the field containing the XHTML and execute the report.